# git tag add a file to a previous tag

Tags: git, git-tag

I would like to know your inputs or recommended work flow in Git on how to add a single file to a previous tag a revision release in Git.
This scenario is seen when say a new Firmware release and the firmware file needs to be available to all release versions (which are tagged).

in CVS, I can simply just `cvs add` the file and tag it V1.2, V1.3, so on. But how about in Git, how do I make this certain file or files available to the tags when the master has already moved forward?

The goal is to make this files available in the repo so that anyone who wants to generate the release versions can grab these files and include them in the release versions.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Since tags point to specific commits, it may not be possible (I have not yet tried, so I may be wrong) to add a file to a previous commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The goal is to make this files available in the repo so that anyone who wants to generate the release versions can grab these files and include them in the release versions.

There is a better way to accomplish that then to change the content of release tags. Its generally bad form to change a release after its been released; when users check out V1.2 they want to get version 1.2.

Consider leaving release tags alone and instead having a `stable` or `maintenance` or `V1.x` branch you keep updated. Consider following [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/) and have bugfixes be released as a new version with a new tag: V1.2.1 and V1.2.2 and so on.

If you want you can provide a `latest` tag to point at the latest release. Or if you maintain multiple versions of your software you can have `V1-latest` which you keep pointed at the latest release of the version 1 branch.

```
# Move the V1-latest tag to the same commit as V1.2.2
git tag -f V1-latest V1.2.2
```

Now to how you can do what you asked...

---

> How do I make this certain file or files available to the tags when the master has already moved forward?

A tags in Git is just a label that points at a commit. You can move them around. Normally `git tag` won't let you do this, tags aren't supposed to move, so you have to force it with `-f`.

So you need to make a new commit with your changes and move the tag there.

1. Check out the tag: `git checkout <name of the tag>`
2. Make whatever changes you like.
3. Commit them.
4. Move the tag to the new commit: `git tag -f <name of the tag>`

Git will tell you you're on a "detached HEAD". That means there's no branch pointing at this commit. That's ok, you can work and make commits. Just don't checkout another branch until you're done and have moved your tag or you'll lose your place.

Thinking about it visually, you have something like this.

```
F [master]
|
E
|
D
|
C {v1.2}
|
```

After you checkout `v1.2`, make your changes and commit you have this.

```
F [master]
|
E
|
D G DETACHED-HEAD
|/
C {v1.2}
|
```

G contains your new changes to `v1.2`. Once you `git tag -f V1.2` you have this.

```
F [master]
|
E
|
D G {v1.2}
|/
C
|
```

Comment: Hi @schwern, thank you for your answer. I just have one concern about this workflow you suggested however. I need to make sure that none of the changes in the master branch is included in the new commit when I move the tag there. it means that I need to retain the files/changes in that tag and just add the file and then commit and retag.

Comment: @SydPao There's no danger of that. Tags are per commit, not per file.

Answer (score 2):

CVS tags individual files, so this makes sense there.

Git doesn't: a tag is just another name for a specific commit.<sup>1</sup>  Commits are immutable: you can't add anything, remove anything, or change anything.  (This is because the commit's "true name" is its SHA-1, which is a crytpographic checksum of every bit that is part of the commit.  Change even a single bit and you change the checksum, getting a new, different commit instead.)

What you can do is delete (or forcibly change) the tag, so that a new tag with the same spelling refers to the new, different commit.  This will confuse anyone who has already copied the old tag, because they'll think they already have the correct tag.  So only do this if you (a) don't care too much about them, (b) are sure they don't exist, and/or (c) are going to tell them that they must delete their wrong tag.

---

<sup>1</sup>In git, a branch name, like `master`, is *also* just a name for one specific commit, except that everyone agrees on a special property of branch-names: they change over time, preferably in a "fast forward" manner, i.e., a future version of `master` may point to a new commit, but whatever that new commit is, it will—or at least, it *should*, under normal conditions—have the current commit in its history.

Tags, unlike branches, don't move (or shouldn't).